# Get Windows user email from Microsoft account

Tags: c#, windows, user-accounts

I'm getting all the Windows users like this:

```
PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Machine, Environment.MachineName);
UserPrincipal ctxUserPrincipal= new UserPrincipal(ctx);
ctxUserPrincipal.Name = "*";
PrincipalSearcher principalSearcher = new PrincipalSearcher();
principalSearcher.QueryFilter = ctxUserPrincipal;
PrincipalSearchResult<Principal> principalSearchResult = principalSearcher.FindAll();

foreach (Principal principal in principalSearchResult)
{
    using (UserPrincipal userPrincipal = (UserPrincipal)principal)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

It works OK but when a Windows account is created with a Microsoft account, `userPrincipal.EmailAddress` is still null.

I need to extract account's emails when they are not "local" but Microsoft-linked. I tried some solutions but none of what I found worked.

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't think you can.  The account information is under the user login and the user needs to have an account on the machine.  So to populate the information local you need to open outlook up to create account on the machine under the user or if it is a POP account setup the email properties which is stored in the user account on the local machine.